# Rendering Grid Layout From JToken in Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

I have created a DocType **MyDocType**.

**DocTypeGridEditor** requires it to be of type **ElementType**, therefore, I checked it to be of that type in the Umbraco Backoffice.

It contains one property: **GridLayout**, i.e:

```
public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken MyGrid => this.Value<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>("myGrid");
```

And in my cshtml I would like to render it but

```
@Html.GetGridHtml()
```

requires first parameter to be of type **IPublishedContent**. 
I am using **UmbracoViewPage** for the template.

Is there a way to render its content?
Is it even possible to render Grid from ElementModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by creating my own extension to the HtmlHelper.
Here is a snippet:

```
public static class GridLayoutExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetGridHtml(this HtmlHelper html, IPublishedElement publishedElement, string propertyAlias)
    {
        if (propertyAlias == null)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }

        var model = publishedElement
            .GetProperty(propertyAlias)
            .GetValue();

        return html.Partial("Grid/bootstrap3", model);
    }
}
```

And now all I need to do is to use it by passing an element which contains GridLayout property.

```
@Html.GetGridHtml2(Model.MyDocType, "gridLayout")
```

And it works flawlessly.